# React native How can I test background tasks in expo?

Tags: react-native, background-task

I know that there are packages for background tasks in expo or just react natives.
Taskmanagers, task-fetch react native task jop and so on.

My problem is how can I check that my apps works background or not by expo?

Is there background mode for expo? I test with real Android device by expo, which connected by terminal.

If there any video about it, Please let me know. I appreciate your help!